# When I send user to another activity it reloads again and again to endless time

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-activity

I have a simple activity in which a user will upload a post, after uploading post user will redirect to Main Activity, but the problem is when the user redirects to the main activity it reloads again and again to endless time.

```
public class ProjectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ImageButton selectProjectImage;
    private Button uploadProjectButton;
    private EditText projectDescription;
    private static final int gallery_pick=1;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private String description;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    // URL of String
    private String downloadUrl;

    //Date and Time
    private String saveCurrentDate , saveCurrentTime , projectRandomName;
    private long countProjects=0;

    // Firebase
    private StorageReference projectImagesRefernce;
    private DatabaseReference usersRef  , projectRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_project);

        //Firebase
        projectImagesRefernce = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        projectRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Projects");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        selectProjectImage=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.select_project_image);
        uploadProjectButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload_project_btn);
        projectDescription=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.project_description);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.update_project_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Upload Project");
        selectProjectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGalley();
            }
        });
```

Here we called upload project onclickListener

```
 uploadProjectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                validateProjectInfo();
            }
        });
    }
```

Remaining code

```
    private void validateProjectInfo()
    {
        description = projectDescription.getText().toString();
        if(imageUri==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select project Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(description))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide description of project", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {

            loadingBar.setTitle("Adding new Project");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait  ...");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            storingImageToFirebaseStorage();
        }
    }

    private void storingImageToFirebaseStorage()
    {
        // For Date
        Calendar calForData = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForData.getTime());

        // For Time
        Calendar calForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calForData.getTime());

        // Random Name
        projectRandomName=saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;



        final StorageReference filepath = projectImagesRefernce.child("project images").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment()
        +projectRandomName + ".jpg");
        filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                        Toast.makeText(ProjectActivity.this,"Image uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        savingProjectInformationToDatabase();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void savingProjectInformationToDatabase()
    {
        projectRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    countProjects =dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                }
                else
                {
                    countProjects=0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        usersRef.child(currentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    String userFullName = dataSnapshot.child("fullName").getValue().toString();
                    String userProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profile image").getValue().toString();
                    HashMap projectMap = new HashMap();
                    projectMap.put("uid" ,currentUserId);
                    projectMap.put("date" ,saveCurrentDate);
                    projectMap.put("time" ,saveCurrentTime);
                    projectMap.put("description" ,description);
                    projectMap.put("projectImageUrl" ,downloadUrl);
                    projectMap.put("profileimage" ,userProfileImage);
                    projectMap.put("fullname" ,userFullName);
                    projectMap.put("counter",countProjects);
                    projectRef.child(currentUserId+projectRandomName).updateChildren(projectMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                        {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(ProjectActivity.this, "Project is updated successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

here we send user to main activity

```
sendUserToMainActivity();
```

Remaining code

```
                      loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(ProjectActivity.this, "Error Occured :" +message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });
    }

    private void openGalley()
    {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent ,gallery_pick);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==gallery_pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null)
        {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            selectProjectImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
```

also here we send user to main activity

```
if(id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            sendUserToMainActivity();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

The above code is all about uploading a post and storing into firebase

```
private void sendUserToMainActivity()
{
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ProjectActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    this.finish();

}
```

Main Activity code

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mtoolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        //Recycler View
        postList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.all_user_post_list);
        postList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        postList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        //Firebase
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserId =mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        projectsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Projects");
        likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");

        addNewProjectBtn =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_new_project_btn);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        navigationView =(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
        navProfileImage =(CircleImageView)navView.findViewById(R.id.setup_profile_image);
        navProfileName =(TextView)navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_name);
        userRef.child(currentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullName"))
                    {
                        String full_name =dataSnapshot.child("fullName").getValue().toString();
                        navProfileName.setText(full_name);
                    }
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profile image"))
                    {
                        String image =dataSnapshot.child("profile image").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(navProfileImage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile name do not exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                user_menu_selector(item);
                return false;
            }
        });
        addNewProjectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sendUserToProjectActivity();
            }
        });


    }


    public  void  updateUserStatus(String state)
    {
        String saveCurrentDate,saveCurrentTime;
        // For Date
        Calendar calForData = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForData.getTime());

        // For Time
        Calendar calForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calForData.getTime());

        Map currentStateMap = new HashMap();
        currentStateMap.put("time" , saveCurrentTime);
        currentStateMap.put("date" , saveCurrentDate);
        currentStateMap.put("type" , state);
        userRef.child(currentUserId).child("userState").updateChildren(currentStateMap);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser==null){
            sendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
        else
        {
            checkUserExitence();
        }
        Query sortPorjects = projectsRef.orderByChild("counter");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<projects> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<projects>()
                        .setQuery(sortPorjects , com.codewithosama.socialapp.projects.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<projects, ProjectViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<projects, ProjectViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjectViewHolder projectViewHolder, int i, @NonNull projects projects)
            {

                final String postKey = getRef(i).getKey();
                projectViewHolder.userName.setText(projects.getFullname());
                projectViewHolder.date.setText(projects.getDate());
                projectViewHolder.time.setText(projects.getTime());
                projectViewHolder.project_description.setText(projects.getDescription());
                Picasso.get().load(projects.getProfileimage()).into(projectViewHolder.user_profile_image);
                Picasso.get().load(projects.getProjectImageUrl()).into(projectViewHolder.project_image);
                projectViewHolder.setLikeButtonStatus(postKey);

                projectViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent clickPostIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , ClickProjectActivity.class);
                        clickPostIntent.putExtra("post_key" ,postKey);
                        startActivity(clickPostIntent);
                    }
                });
                projectViewHolder.comment_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent commentsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , CommentsActivity.class);
                        commentsIntent.putExtra("post_key" ,postKey);
                        startActivity(commentsIntent);
                    }
                });


                projectViewHolder.like_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        likesChecker = true;
                        likesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                                if(likesChecker.equals(true))
                                {
                                    if(dataSnapshot.child(postKey).hasChild(currentUserId))
                                    {
                                        likesRef.child(postKey).child(currentUserId).removeValue();
                                        likesChecker  =false;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        likesRef.child(postKey).child(currentUserId).setValue(true);
                                        likesChecker=false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ProjectViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_projects_layout , parent,false);
                ProjectViewHolder viewHolder = new ProjectViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }

        };
        postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

        updateUserStatus("online");
    }
    public static  class ProjectViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        CircleImageView user_profile_image;
        ImageView project_image;
        TextView time , date , project_description  , userName ,display_likes;
        ImageButton like_btn ,comment_btn;
        int countLikes;
        String currentUserId;
        DatabaseReference likesRef;

        public ProjectViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            user_profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.project_profile_image);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.project_user_name);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.project_time);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.project_date);
            project_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_project_description);
            project_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_project_image);
            like_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_btn);
            comment_btn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);
            display_likes=itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_likes);
            likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
            currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        }
        public void setLikeButtonStatus(final String postKey)
        {
            likesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(postKey).hasChild(currentUserId))
                    {
                        countLikes = (int)dataSnapshot.child(postKey).getChildrenCount();
                        like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.clap);
                        display_likes.setText((Integer.toString(countLikes))+" Claps");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        countLikes = (int)dataSnapshot.child(postKey).getChildrenCount();
                        like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_clap);
                        display_likes.setText((Integer.toString(countLikes))+" Claps");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });
        }


    }


    private void checkUserExitence()
    {
        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id))
                {
                    sendUserToSetupActivity();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
            {
            }
        });
    }


    private void sendUserToProjectActivity()
    {
        Intent addNewProjectIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , ProjectActivity.class);
        startActivity(addNewProjectIntent);

    }






    private void sendUserToSetupActivity()
    {
        Intent setupIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this , SetupActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        updateUserStatus("offline");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        updateUserStatus("offline");
    }

    private void sendUserToLoginActivity()
    {
        Intent loginIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this , LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }
    private void sendUserToSettingsActivity()
    {
        Intent loginIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this , SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    }
    private void sendUserToProfileActivity()
    {
        Intent profileIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this , ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(profileIntent);
    }
    private void sendUserToFindFriendsActivity()
    {
        Intent profileIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this , FindFriendsActivity.class);
        startActivity(profileIntent);
    }

    private void sendUserToFriendsActivity()
    {
        Intent friendsIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this , FriendsActivity.class);
        startActivity(friendsIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void user_menu_selector(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_project:
                sendUserToProjectActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                sendUserToProfileActivity();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_home:
                Toast.makeText(this, "it is working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_friends:
                sendUserToFriendsActivity();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_find_friends:
                sendUserToFindFriendsActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_messages:
                sendUserToFriendsActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                sendUserToSettingsActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                updateUserStatus("offline");
                sendUserToLoginActivity();
                mAuth.signOut();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

this reloads again and again in logcat

```
2020-07-27 12:09:42.770 2626-5215/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.codewithosama.socialapp/.MainActivity} from uid 10174
2020-07-27 12:09:42.771 2626-5215/? W/ActivityManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=com.codewithosama.socialapp/.MainActivity }
2020-07-27 12:09:42.812 2626-3376/? W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.codewithosama.socialapp callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@851e89a
2020-07-27 12:09:42.917 6802-6802/com.codewithosama.socialapp W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
2020-07-27 12:09:42.978 818-818/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing com.codewithosama.socialapp/com.codewithosama.socialapp.MainActivity to com.codewithosama.socialapp/com.codewithosama.socialapp.MainActivity#1
2020-07-27 12:09:43.033 2626-3045/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher3/.CustomizationPanelLauncher (has extras)} from uid 1000
2020-07-27 12:09:43.042 3274-3274/? I/GoogleInputMethod: onFinishInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
2020-07-27 12:09:43.042 3274-3274/? I/GoogleInputMethod: onStartInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
```

Comment: This is too much code for anyone to look at. You need to narrow down your problem. You should debug the code and step through it. Especially if you say that it reloads again and again, it should be easy to set a few breakpoints and see what the code is actually doing. Once you've done that you can open a new question with the information you have learned and we can help you. Nobody is going to read all that code.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but as coming in the logs-

```
W/ActivityManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=com.codewithosama.socialapp/.MainActivity }
```

check if you have `android:launchMode="singleTop"` under **MainActivity** in AndroidManifest.xml

Discard/Delete the launchMode.
Please Update me about it as well.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.codewithosama.socialapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

</manifest>

Comment: this is main activity , no lauch mode is there

Comment: I went through your code again, not able to find the resolution, could you update the MainActivity as well, it can help me to find my path to solution.

Comment: I mean could you provide the MainActivity's code on the question just like you provided other code

Comment: @speedprogrammer did you find any fix for the issue ?

Comment: No no brother , just wait I am uploading Mian Activity code also

Comment: @speedprogrammer let me have a look, I'll update you if I got something

Comment: it is very messy, it would be very difficult for you to find something that is important and worthy. You can share with me your ideas, your thoughts and your reason about this problem why it is occurring, maybe my minds will directly click into it

Comment: try using breakpoint to debug the code, so you can see where exactly its failing, you can try to optimize code as well to structure it further. This might help you to find errors. Use log statements to check which code block is executing which one is not.  What still concerns me is "W/ActivityManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" ,  I still didn’t get time to look into the main activity code’s.

Comment: I understand Logs .. What are breakpoints ? is it a simple break statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218816/discussion-between-nikhil-sharma-and-speed-programmer).